# How many IP can I fit into an FPGA?

Tags: fpga

How can I calculate if a certain IP will fit into a certain FPGA?
If the unit of measurement of an FPGA size is the LUT, I need that FPGA lut >= core lut
For example, can I put a [S1 core](http://www.srisc.com/?s1) (37k look up tables) into a [Spartan6 LX9 board](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1812459948/minispartan6-a-powerful-fpga-board-and-easy-to-use) (xxx luts)?

Many thanks

Comment: You can only estimate it as different FPGAs provide different types of LUTs and additional logic. For your question regarding the S1 core and the Spartan6 LX9: It will not fit as the Virtex5 and Spartan6 series both have 6-input LUTs. Therefore, the 37k should be pretty accurate. However, according to the Product Table the LX9 only provides around 5.6k.

Comment: There is a reference board for OpenSPARC [link](http://www.digilentinc.com/Products/Detail.cfm?NavPath=2,400,795&Prod=XUPV5). Beware, it is **not** cheap.

Comment: Yes, I had a look at that previously. I thought I could access to a Sparc-based platform with a fistful of dollars. Silly me

Comment: Well, you need a rather large fist. There are smaller 32bits SPARCs (instead of the 64bits S1), as well as many other open source cores : OpenRISC, MIPS subsets...

Answer (score 1):

The estimate given in the description of the IP core is just that: an estimate. Actual size and layout may vary during synthesis, depending on

- other components
- stuck signals
- timing constraints
- optimization level

and possibly a few others. The estimate given for a particular FPGA architecture is usually not that far off in absolute space used, but placement of an IP block will affect placement of other components as well, in a highly nonlinear way.

Thus, your best bet is to try whether your project still compiles to a valid output file, and whether timings can be met.

There is no hard boundary between "compiles" and "no longer compiles", but rather a fuzzy area where it works with a certain probability (and retrying a failed compilation may work), and the higher you go, that number drops towards zero.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a small project with your IP and create a wrapper arround it and run it through your synthesis tool. That will give you an estimate on how much space it will take.

You can "play" with different optimization to find the right choice for tour project.

In Vivado, you do not need a wrapper. You can use the "out of context" option for the IP. But Viva do does not support Spartan FPGAs.